# Problem with Styling and Visibility while showing modal in Angular 4 Application --

Tags: html, css, angular, modal-dialog, z-index

Facing problem with opening and displaying a modal in my Angular4 .NET Application. I would click a link and consecutively a modal would show. In my case the date link for invoice number [pl see the image].

I followed the approach shown here -- http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

Now what I have currently is, my opaque screen blocking the background but the modal is not displaying as I was hoping for. Like this
[image]

I don't know why the modal didn't appear. I am guessing z-index problem maybe? Cause I do not see any console errors. So probably not angular code related matter. Most likely CSS is what I feel. My main app screen is divided into 2 segments as you can see, col-sm-3 and col-sm-9 body content.

Basically this is what I wrote to test my code.
my main app window layout -

```
    <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <nav-menu></nav-menu>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <alert-component></alert-component>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my modal related html --

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-radius:8px; background:linear-gradient(50deg, #e1ecfa, #f2fbde); text-align:right; margin-left:12px; padding:10px;">
        <b style="color:darkblue">Invoices issued to this customer</b>

        <ul style="list-style:none" *ngFor="let i of iObj">
            <li (click)="openInvoiceModal('custom-modal-1')" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right">
                <a>
                    <b>{{i.inv_id}}, on {{i.inv_date}}</b>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
*** my test modal ***
<modal id="custom-modal-1">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h1>Invoice Modal!</h1>
            <p>
                Home page text: Hello There!
            </p>
            <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');">
                Close
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
</modal>
```

typescript with this page --

```
openInvoiceModal(id: string) {
        this.modalService.open(id);
    }

    closeInvoiceModal(id: string) {
        this.modalService.close(id);
    }
```

All the other files and code are the same as has been written in that link/tutorial. I tried experimenting at one place with z-index also. But it didn't serve the purpose. So I am baffled.
A few alterations in the modalcomponent file also according to my layout css etc, so I am posting it here.

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() id: string;
    private element: JQuery;

    constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private el: ElementRef) {
        this.element = $(el.nativeElement);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let modal = this;

        // ensure id attribute exists
        if (!this.id) {
            console.error('modal must have an id');
            return;
        }

        this.element.appendTo('.container-fluid');

        this.element.on('click', function (e: any) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            if (!target.closest('.modal-body').length) {
                modal.close();
            }
        });

        this.modalService.add(this);
    }

    // remove self from modal service when directive is destroyed
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.modalService.remove(this.id);
        this.element.remove();
    }


    open(): void {
        this.element.show();
        $('.container-fluid').addClass('modal-open');
    }

    // close modal
    close(): void {
        this.element.hide();
        $('.container-fluid').removeClass('modal-open');
    }

}
```

I am not sure why the modal itself is not showing. Although the opaque background is being called means - I am going the right way. ALMOST!
What am I missing? Where is the glitch? Surely it has to be some small tricky part that I am failing to grab! Kindly guide me.
Let me know if you need more code stubs from me to understand my scenario. I will be happy to share.

In anticipation,

Comment: did you try `position: absolute` ?, i think it's mainly these 2 problems, z-index and positioning

Comment: Hi @Hussein thanks for replying,
okk let me try it out [position:absolute]. I will report back,

Comment: Does your `app.module.ts` have `entryComponents`? Try adding `entryComponents: [ModalComponent]` in your `@NgModule`

Comment: Hi @PeterKim no I haven't got it in my app.module.ts. Okay I will try that too, ..... although the original tutorial I was following didn't have this either; that is why;

Comment: Hi @PeterKim I tried both -- position:absolute and adding ModalComponent within entryComponent. Didn't do the trick!  : [[

Comment: Hi @Hussein I tried both -- position:absolute and adding ModalComponent within entryComponent. Didn't do the trick!  : [[

Comment: I tried by keeping ModalComponent within declarations, within entryComponents and with both. All 3 possibilities. Nope. I also experimented around with z-index. Not sure what it is. Still does not work! [position:absolute] does not fix it either.

Comment: Hey did you in the end find a solution? I guess I stumbled on a similar problem.